# SOLR: Setting up index time synonyms

Tags: solr

I am trying to get synonyms working correctly, I want to map  floor locker   to    storage locker

currently searching for storage locker produces results were as searching for floor locker  does not produce any results.
I have the following setup for index time synonyms:

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" omitNorms="false">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true" tokenizerFactory="KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <charFilter class="solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" />
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
        <filter class="solr.EnglishPorterFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory" />
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
......
```

And my synonyms.txt looks like this:

```
floor locker=>storage locker
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does your query look like?

Comment: I'm afraid that I don't know enough about Dismax queries to really comment here ... however, is it possible that the synonym is not being recognized because you're not searching for an exact phrase?

Comment: I have tried this even without being dismax in multiple ways...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the order of the analysis chain wrong. You should put the char filter first, then the tokenizer. The synonym filter can be immediately after that. The remainder of the filters are in the right order, or at least a good order.